# HTML/CSS "Put icons in search results"

Tags: html, css, icons, searchbar

Hello everyone this is my first post here,

I got a question. How can i put icons (images) inside my search results of my search bar. This is my search bar code:

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: source,
        select: function( event, ui ) { 
            window.location.href = ui.item.value;
        }
    });
});
```

```
   <script> 
    var source = [
                  { value: "test.html",
                     label: "test"
                    },

                  { value: "test2html",
                     label: "test2"
                    },       
                 ];
```

How I want it to look

[image]

Thanks for reading and I hope someone can help me.

Comment: I guess you would have to add your icons as part of your label, or have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885431/jquery-ui-autocomplete-images-in-the-results-overlay-not-outside-like-the-dem

Comment: this page maybe help you :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35173180/search-icon-in-search-field

Comment: @mehdifarhadi that is putting an icon in the textbox, not in the results